# Contrasts in ANOVA - need intuitions to understand its sum of squares and its degree of freedom

Tags: anova, degrees-of-freedom, contrasts, sums-of-squares

I have two questions about contrasts in ANOVA for testing the hypothesis that $\sum_i c_i y_i = 0$.

1. How is the sum of squares for contrasts $\{c_i\}$, $SS_C = \frac{(\sum_i {c_i \bar{y_i}})^2}{\sum_i c_i^2 /n_i}$, derived? I understand the denominator is the variance of the numerator, but I do not see why we need it. In the case of usual residual sum of squares $SS_E$, we only compute $\sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})^2$ without any denominator. Or is it just a 'definition'?
2. The book said this sum of squares $SS_C$ has *one* degree of freedom. Why is this so? In the case of $SS_E$, we would have $n-1$ degree of freedoms, which make sense because we lose one degree of freedom to $\bar{y}$.

Comment: The denominator isn't the variance.  It standardizes the sum for the weights chosen and for the possibility of unequal $n_i$s.